# Got error: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer`

Tags: keras

```
for i in range(seq.size(1) - 1):<br>
    it = seq[:, i].clone()<br>  
    # break if all the sequences end <br>
    if i >= 1 and seq[:, i].sum() == 0:<br>
        break <br>
    output, state = self.get_logprobs_state(it, fc_feats, att_feats, <br>      
                    pp_att_feats, att_masks, state) <br>
    outputs[:, i].assign(output) <br>
outputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(outputs) <br>
model = Model([inputs_fc, inputs_att, inputs_seq], outputs) <br>
```

I tried to use Lambda, also not work.
Here is the error:

> ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras
>   `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found:
>   Tensor("Variable_1/read:0", shape=(10, 15, 9488), dtype=float32)

Comment: Well you have to use a Lambda layer or similar, the error is quite clear, i you tried this and didn't work, please include the code that produces the problem. Also you shouldn't need to use convert_to_tensor if your whole code uses tensorflow.

Comment: Thank you,  Matias Valdenegro. Don't know how to use Lambda because outputs[:, I] is a variable. For outputs[:, i].assign(output), it is  <tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(10, 15, 9488) dtype=float32_ref>

Comment: How is your output variable computed exactly? You have to wrap the whole thing into a Lambda layer.

Comment: I dont think you can do what you want to here. You need all inputs to be a tensor which this is not for Keras